# Calling a Javascript in my razor page from a controller in MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In my controller I have this function:

```
Function AppError() As ActionResult
        Dim myScript As Object = "popup(" + Properties.postError + ")"
        Return RedirectToAction("main", myScript)
    End Function
```

With this function I want to call my razor page where I have a Javascript named `popup` whith a parameter `Properties.postError`.
My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var errMsg;
    function popup(msg) {
        errMsg = msg;
        window.alert(errMsg);
        window.window.focus();
        if (window.confirm)
            errmsg = '';
        msg = '';
    }
</script>
```

What I need is to popup the error message.
I follow the programm thru my debugger and I saw that it goes to my page.
But no error message window raise up.
I have already search in the web for this option without any success.
Is someone to assist me on this issue?

**ADDITION - 16/2/19 12:50**
what I have done so far is the following:

```
Function CBError() As ActionResult
        Dim myScript As Object = "popup(" + Properties.postError + ")"
        ViewData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("ScriptName", myScript))
        Return View("main", myScript)
    End Function
```

As we can see I've change the function by addiding the `ViewData`
I Add a value pair arguments 1) the name 2) the value
The action of addition it works just fine and the dictionery receive it.
I my script (which is in my reazor page) I put the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var vd = @ViewData.Item(0);
       function popup(msg) {
            var errMsg;
        errMsg = msg;
        window.alert(errMsg);
        window.window.focus();
        if (window.confirm)
            errmsg = '';
        msg = '';
        //{ window.location.href = "/" }
    }
</script>
```

When I stop (with the bebugger) in the instruction `var vd = @ViewData.Item(0);` I see that the `ViewData` is complitely empty. No values no nothing. 
I also add this `window.onload = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyScript);` 
And in debugger threw me an error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"

Is there somone to instruct me why that happen?

**ADDITION - 16/2/19 20:00**
New version of function and Script

```
Function CBError() As ActionResult
        Dim myScript As Object = Properties.postError
        ViewData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)("Message", myScript))
        Return View("main")
    End Function<br/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){
  alert("@ViewData.Values(0)");
  });
</script>
```

With this version I put the `message` value to the `ViewData`
But when the program comes to the point of `script` then all the `ViwData` is empty. 
No Values no Keys no nothing.
It seems somewhere in the middle it lose all the data

**FINAL UPDATE 17/2/19 11:13**
The problem has been solved ... but not by the way we are wearing.
It was solved in an extremely simple way.
What we were asking for was to get the error message on the page we are in. From any point of the code.
So I followed the method of rendering the message to property and I read this message from the page with the following `Javascript`.
The function is:

```
Function CodePage_Error() As ActionResult
        Return View("main")
    End Function
```

End the Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ("@Properties.InnerError" !== "") {
            var msg = "@Properties.InnerError";
            window.alert(msg);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

});
    
The Javascript is placed in the `mainLayout.vbhtml` file

Generally speaking, it turned out that the transfer method from the controller to the page is not possible in the MVC4 environment

Comment: Hi, I was looking for this, but I've not View method in my project. (my page is a RazorPages.PageModel derived class). Where is defined the View method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the error message to the page via Viewbag, and then put the pop up script inside the document ready javascript function to check the message and display the error if required.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "this is your message";
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
alert("@ViewBag.Message");
});
```

Comment: You mean that, to put the `ViewBag` into the function and into the razor page ??? Have you ever try that?  Because I have already did it and... nothing...

Comment: Please have a look in my last Addition. The same happen with the `ViewBag`

Answer (score 1):

I think passing JS code through `RedirectToAction` route value parameter is not a good idea because some special characters will be encoded. You should use either `ViewBag` or viewmodel properties and pass the script to view in unencoded state.

Here is an example setup:

1) Use `ViewBag` or a viewmodel property to contain the script you want to execute in the view.

```
Public Function AppError() As ActionResult
    ' define Properties.postError here

    Dim myScript As String = "popup(" + Properties.postError + ")"
    ViewBag.MyScript = myScript

    Return View()
End Function
```

2) Use an event handler e.g. `window.onload` assigned with `@Html.Raw()` from `ViewBag` or viewmodel property to pass unencoded function call inside  `<script>` tag. The event handling must be placed outside `function` block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var errMsg;
    function popup(msg) {
        errMsg = msg;
        window.alert(errMsg);
        window.window.focus();
        if (window.confirm)
            errmsg = '';
        msg = '';
    }

    // the popup will be called here
    window.onload = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.MyScript)
</script>
```

Note that `window.onload` will pop up the message after the view is loaded, if you want to pop up the message in another event use any desired [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) instead (also check [list of available JS DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)).

Comment: Dear.. good day. You mean to substitute my popup function with `viewBag.MyScript`

Comment: @ Tetsuya Yamamoto Please have a look in my addition.